# let $a_n<c_n$ $\sum_n^\infty a_n=A$ and $\sum_n^\infty c_n=C$ $B\in(A,C)$ construct b_n such that $\sum_n^\infty b_n=B$

Tags: calculus, analysis

I find this question tricky. I do not know how to approach  a problem like this. I took a look at Direct comparison test proof, but it was not helpful, because no series were constructed there.

So what I want is a hint where to start.

Comment: What prevents you from having $b_1=B$ and $b_n=0$ for $n>1$?

Comment: Please use the body of the Question to give a detailed problem statement, not relying solely on the title for this burden.  It might seem expeditious or to establish how "simple" your problem is, but this isn't borne out in practice because it invites confusion and the perception that you quickly passed along an assigned exercise without thinking through what the problem asks or how to approach it.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a hint:
$$B=\frac{B-A}{C-A}C+\frac{C-B}{C-A}A.$$